# NullPointerException when trying to mock response from WebFlux service layer

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, spring-webflux

I'm trying to write a unit test for a method in the service layer of a WebFlux application which processes the response of another service that makes a REST call and returns a Mono of the result.
I'm already testing the nested service using WebTestClient in it's own unit tests so am trying to mock out the response from it using Mockito but am encountering a NullPointerException as if the result isn't being mocked.

I'm relatively new to async/reactive patterns so not sure if I'm doing this wrong or if it's Mockito not playing nicely with the async nature of react however it works fine if it's not a nested service call that is being mocked?

I've replicated it in a minimal example that show's it's purely the mocking of the nested service which isn't working as expected, where `NestedService.doRestCall()` returns a `Mono<String>`:

```
@Service
public class ExampleService {
  private final NestedService nestedService;

  @Autowired
  public ExampleService(final NestedService nestedService) {
    this.nestedService = nestedService;
  }

  public Mono<String> methodToTest() {
    return nestedService.doRestCall()
      .map(data -> data + "-test");
  }
}
```

And the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class ExampleServiceTests {
  @Mock
  private NestedService nestedServiceMock;
  @InjectMocks
  private ExampleService exampleService;

  @Before
  public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
  }

  @Test
  public void test() {
    when(nestedServiceMock.doRestCall()).thenReturn(Mono.just("foo"));

    StepVerifier.create(exampleService.methodToTest())
      .expect("foo-test")
      .verifyComplete();
  }
}
```

I get the following NullPointerException trace triggered from the .map() call in the ExampleService line, I've also tried using flatMap() but get the same error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.service.ExampleService.methodToTest(ExampleService.java:18)
    at com.example.service.ExampleServiceTests.test(ExampleServiceTests.java:33)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You initialize your mocks twice:

- first by spring runner
- then by MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

Lets inspect the variables in the `setup` method with debugger:

Before `initMocks`:

```
nestedServiceMock = {NestedService$MockitoMock$267376363@5567} "nestedServiceMock"
exampleService = {ExampleService@5568}
```

After `initMocks`:

```
nestedServiceMock = {NestedService$MockitoMock$267376363@5661} "nestedServiceMock"
exampleService = {ExampleService@5568} 
exampleService.nestedServiceMock = {NestedService$MockitoMock$267376363@5567} "nestedServiceMock"
```

You can clearly see that the `nestedServiceMock` was re-initialized, but the `exampleService` was not, and still holds reference to the old nested object.

To solve, get rid of Spring boot annotations.
Here, cleaned-up version with JUnit5:

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class ExampleServiceTest {
    @Mock
    private NestedService nestedServiceMock;
    @InjectMocks
    private ExampleService exampleService;
    
    @Test
    public void test() {
        when(nestedServiceMock.doRestCall()).thenReturn(Mono.just("foo"));

        StepVerifier.create(exampleService.methodToTest())
                .expectNext("foo-test")
                .verifyComplete();
    }
}
```